# Location regex - better way?

Tags: regex, nginx

Is there a better (less expensive) way of doing the following?

```
    location ~ \/..-..\/account\/(\bdeath-star-canteen\b|\bcake-or-death\b|\bcovered-in-bees\b) {
            return 301 https://www.example.com/example/expired-account;
    }
```

which should match:

```
http://www.example.com/en-gb/account/death-star-canteen
http://www.example.com/en-gb/account/cake-or-death
http://www.example.com/en-gb/account/covered-in-bees
```

and redirect them to an expired account page? Where en-gb can vary based on locale?

Also is it required to escape the / in nginx URL regex expressions?

Answer (score 1):

It's not really expensive or you should clarify what expensive means in this context but there is a *better* way to do it:

```
location ~ /..-../account/(c(ake-or-death|overed-in-bees)|death-star-canteen) {
    return 301 https://www.example.com/example/expired-account;
}
```

There is [no need to escape slashes](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).

Comment: I use expensive to mean in terms of adding unnecessary processing to each request.